# How to access the methods in this class in Java

Tags: java, android

I have the following click listener in android:

```
    this.startButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override


            public void onClick(View v) {
                flag.set(false);
                   Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable()  {
                    int updateInterval = 4000; //=4 second
                    ImageView currentImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture);


                    public void x(){//dosomething}




                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(!flag.get()) {
                            currentImage.postDelayed(this, updateInterval);
                            picture.setImageResource(images[current_image_index]);
                            caption.setText(captions[current_image_index]);
                            current_image_index++;
                            current_image_index = current_image_index % images.length;
                        }
                    }
                };

                myRunnable.run();

            }
    }

    );
```

However I have another onClickListener that need to call the method x() from myRunnable. However I seem to not be able to do so. The context here is that when startButton is clicked, it causes images to be changed every 4 seconds, but I have another button called nextButton that when clicked changes the image and must reset the update interval, otherwise the next image will change inconsistently when the nextButton is pressed, thanks!

Comment: This questions needs a minimum verifiable code example.

Comment: This code is not syntactically valid.

Comment: Pretty sure it's going to lock the main UI thread as well.  vs new Thread(myRunnable).start().

Comment: what is wrong with the code?

Comment: What is **not** wrong with the code? It's not valid because of the line `public void x(){//dosomething}`

Answer (score 0):

The program would not run as expected. You are overriding a method inside an

overriden method. Better still create a separate method to handle that event and

then call it up in your eventListener. Hope this helps